# Chart.js 2.2.x - How to access the pixel coordinate of a point in my dataset

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js, chart.js2

I'm creating a plugin for my chart (in ChartJS 2.2.2), and for that I need the pixel position of each point of my dataset.

When inspecting the `chart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0]`, I get back the following object:

[image]

But when I access the x field directly in my plugin code, the values returned are different. The commands:

`chart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].dataset._children[0]._model.x` and
`chart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[0]._model.x` (which yields the same value when looking it up in the chrome debugger) both return **x = 3** instead of 44.67.

Why is this happening? What is the proper way to access the pixel coordinate of a point in my dataset?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce the error](https://jsfiddle.net/1ykvuxch/). Graphically speaking (looking by yourself, without a debugger), would it be `x=3` or `x=44` ?

Comment: if there is no animation does it produce the correct result?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tektiv I will update the answer with what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is called multiple times, I was debugging only the initial values for the coordinates. Turns out the last calls were made with the correct value for X (44.67). I think this was happening because initially the canvas containing the chart was hidden (using ng-hide), only after init it was being shown.

It was rendered correctly though.